# How to restrict branch release branch creation only from develop branch

Tags: git, gitlab, hook, githooks

I'd like to restrict developers from creating release branches from some other branches. Basically, release branches should be allowed to create only from develop branch.

I am working on gitlab and i don't see an option to achieve this from gitlab side.

Is there any way to do that using some hooks?

Comment: If you want to restrict that, you'd also need to prevent them to ever `reset` to anything, because if it's not the case, anyone can create a branch following your "restrictions" then just reset to whatever branch/tag/commit they want.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are no server hooks for branches creation.

Here is [the GIT official complete list](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). As you can see the only allowed are `pre-receive`, `update` and `post-receive`.

I suggest you to don't prevent the branch creatio, but write a `pre-receive` to enforce rules on it such not allow to push to release branches not created from the `develop` branch.

Here is the [Gitlab hooks writing guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html).

Regards.